# How to compute mathematical operations faster?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following C++ code,

and the complexCorrelationLoop is as follows:

```
void complexMath::complexCorrelationLoop(fftw_complex *in_1, fftw_complex *in_2, fftw_complex *out, int N, int k1, int k2) {
for(int k=k1; k<k2; k++) {
    complexMath::complexCorrelation(in_1, in_2, out, N, k);
}
```

}

with complexCorrelation:

```
void complexMath::complexCorrelation(fftw_complex *in_1, fftw_complex *in_2, fftw_complex *out, int N, int k) {
fftw_complex *inConj = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
fftw_complex *mulOut = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
for(int m=0; m<N; m++){
    complexMath::complexConjugate(in_1, inConj, m);
    complexMath::complexScalarMultiplication(inConj, in_2, mulOut, m, m+k, m);
    out[k][0] += mulOut[m][0];
    out[k][1] += mulOut[m][1];
}
fftw_free(inConj); fftw_free(mulOut);
```

}

complexConjugate and complexScalarMultiplication does exactly what they are named. Now, I have the following code in the main():

```
  boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&complexMath::complexCorrelationLoop, &cM, in_1, in_1, out_1, nfft, 0, 101));
  boost::thread thread2(boost::bind(&complexMath::complexCorrelationLoop, &cM, in_1, in_1, out_1, nfft, 101, 201));
```

and

```
cM.complexCorrelationLoop(in_1, in_1, out_2, nfft, 0, 200);
```

what I wanted to do is to make complexCorrelationLoop parallel, so that it would run faster. because I need it to make the computations really fast, nfft here in my example is 1.000.000, so the loops are kind of huge actually, 200*1.000.000 etc. But the single for loop for 200 runs about 4 times faster than 2 seperate threads with 100 loops each. This is probably because creating and joining the threads are actually costly.

So what I want to do is in some manner, make this process faster. I don't have any ideas other than threading and apperantly it doesn't work in my case. I have read about threadpools but I am unsure how to implement it to my  case. Does anybody have any suggestions or maybe some links for me to read further on issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *This is probably because creating and joining the threads are actually costly.* - Indeed. Threading creates some overhead, so it's only useful if there are significant chunks of calculations that each thread can execute without having to communicate with the others. The advantage of thread pools, is that you can initialize the threads once and recycle them to perform background tasks. For a program that has to run all kinds of tasks in parallel, a thread pool can save on the overhead of creating those threads.

Comment: so a threadpool is actually what I need? but how to make sure threadpools "join", i.e. they all finish their job and properly write their outputs to corresponding places for further operations? I have read a couple of sources but couldn't grasp the idea. Do you maybe have a good source I can read?

Comment: C++ Concurrency in Action Practical Multithreading actually has a chapter (9.1) on thread pools. I'd look there.

Comment: Thanks @bku_drytt i will check it out.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do fftw_malloc on each iteration? can't you reuse the existing objects from some pool?

Comment: i get what you mean @Zeks , i ll do that. thanks.

Comment: Here they show how to do complex multiplication using 2.5 instructions instead of 6 per sample. https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/9/b/7/b/1000-SSE.pdf I imagine this will be useful for you

Comment: I read the presentation but didnt quite get it. so does this mean if i write my code in a particular way the processor automatically makes it 2.5 instructions per sample instead of 6, or do i have to write a completely different code in a completely different language?